# Help with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need some help if possible with the following problem....

1. `atomsClause :: Clause ! [Atom]` This function must take a Clause and return the set of Atoms of that Clause. Note that the set should not contain any duplicates.
2. `atoms :: Formula![Atom]` This function must take a Formula return the set of Atoms of a Formula.
   Note that the set should not contain any duplicates.
3. `isLiteral :: Literal ! Clause ! Bool` This function returns True if the given Literal can be found
   within the Clause.
4. `flipSymbol :: Model ! Atom ! Model` This function must take a Model and an Atom and flip the
   truth value of the atom in the model.

Here is the code:

```
module Algorithm where

import System.Random
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

type Atom = String
type Literal = (Bool,Atom)
type Clause = [Literal]
type Formula = [Clause]
type Model = [(Atom, Bool)]
type Node = (Formula, ([Atom], Model))

atomsClause :: Clause -> [Atom]
atomsClause = undefined

atoms :: Formula -> [Atom]
atoms = undefined

isLiteral :: Literal -> Clause -> Bool
isLiteral = undefined

flipSymbol :: Model -> Atom -> Model
flipSymbol = undefined
```

Thank you.

I was thinking for the first one to write it like this......

```
atomsClause :: Clause -> [Atom]
atomsClause [(Bool,Atom)] =[a|(b,a)<-(Bool,Atom)]
```

...is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not right.

The pattern you match is simply a singleton list. You actually want to match the whole list to work with it. It could look like this:

```
atomsClause clauses = [a|(b,a)<-clauses]
```

What does this function does? Let's see... it takes the atom of each clause but there's no filtering. You can archive what you want using the `nub` function of `Data.List`. So your function looks like this:

```
atomsClause clauses = nub [a|(b,a)<-clauses]
```

Now, we can get rid of the comprehension using a map. We just map the function `snd` onto clauses:

```
atomsClause clauses = nub (map snd clauses)
```

And that's it! If you like it short, you can use this pointless function instead:

```
atomsClause = nub . map snd
```

Comment: I've done it like this and it returns ok....atomsClause xs =nub [a|(b,a)<-xs]...thank you for the reply...but I really need some advice for the second one...sorry ,but I haven't programmed in haskell for a long time

Comment: You may consider using `concat`, which collapses a list of two layers (`[[a]]`) into a list of one layer (`[a]`). Your function would be something like `atoms f = atomsClause (concat f)`, or maybe `atoms = atomsClause . concat`. PS: You may accept my answer and vote it up. Just klick onto the green mark or the grey triangle upwards.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer ...I really want to take this opportunity and learn haskell....is it ok if I continue to ask you some questions.....for example the third one I was thinking of writing it like this isLiteral (b,a) cs = or[x==b && y==a|(x,y)<-cls],but I get the error Exception: Prelude.undefined

Comment: ah no...I solved the error ...andthe code is isLiteral (b,a) cs = or[x==b && y==a|(x,y)<-cs]..there was a mystake at the end

Comment: yes the code work:D...is there any way to write isLiteral (b,a) cs = or[x==b && y==a|(x,y)<-cs] as a shorter version....any advice for the last one?

Comment: @Landei: or even short: `isLiteral = any . (==)`